# Spring get link to an entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, in my RestController I want to return the Location of newly created object. Is there a way to reverse the @RequestMapping's and not hardcode how to build the URL?

```
@RestController
@ExposesResourceFor(BookInstance.class)
public class BookInstanceController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/bookInstances", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<BookInstance> createBookInstance(@RequestBody BookInstance bookInstance){
    BookInstance createdBookInstance = bookInstanceRepository.save(bookInstance);

    return ResponseEntity.created(**reverseURL(createdBookInstance)**);
//      return new ResponseEntity<BookInstance>(createdBookInstance, HttpStatus.CREATED);
//      return createdBookInstance;
    }
}
```

I always see people hard-coding their URL construction in this function, which just leaves me without words....

Of course I also have a GET function in the same class (otherwise there wouldn't be anything to reverse)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bookInstances/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<?> findOne(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        BookInstance bookInstance = bookInstanceRepository.findOne(id);
        if(bookInstance == null){
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<BookInstance>(bookInstance, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution that uses a Resource assembler:

```
public class BookInstanceResource extends Resource<BookInstance> {

    public BookInstanceResource(Book content, Link... links) {
        super(content, links);
    }

}

public class BookInstanceResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<BookInstance, BookInstanceResource> {

    public BookInstanceResourceAssembler() {
        super(BookInstanceController.class, BookInstanceResource.class)
    }

    @Override
    public BookInstanceResource toResource(BookInstance bookInstance) {
        // linkTo requires the following static import:
        // import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
        ControllerLinkBuilder builder = linkTo(BookInstance.class).slash("bookInstances").slash(bookInstance);

        return new BookInstanceResource(bookInstance,
                                        builder.withSelfRel(),
                                        builder.withRel("bookInstance");
        }
}
```

In your controller class:

```
@Autowired
private BookInstanceResourceAssembler resourceAssembler;

@GetMapping(value = "/bookInstances/{id}")
ResponseEntity findOne(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    BookInstance bookInstance = bookInstanceRepository.findOne(id);
    if(bookInstance == null){
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    BookInstanceResource resource = resourceAssembler.toResource(bookInstance);

    return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create(resource.getLink("self").getHref()))
                         .body(resource);
}
```

Comment: What type of declaration have you made for TaskResource in the first code snippet. Could you please tell me from where it is loading the class?

Comment: `TaskResource` was just a dumb copy-paste issue. Fixed.

Comment: This is "hand built" link imho. See @EralpB answer for a bit easier (through different) approach.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by adding this to my class:

```
@Autowired EntityLinks entityLinks;
```

and using some of the HATEOAS features of Spring.

```
Link link = entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(BookInstance.class, createdBookInstance.getId()).expand();
return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create(link.getHref())).build();
```

**Note:** In the above lines createdBookInstance is nothing but returning object after creating record in DB.

Comment: I have got the execption while creating the link from entityLinks saying no plugin available for creating link for type. Did you added any of specific dependencies/plugin's for this?

Answer (score 3):

Since other solutions are not compatible with my source code, I have struggled a lot to find the solution for returning the URL of the newly created entity access API. Personally I feel @EralpB solution would be simple. But, I faced an issue with SimpleEntityPlugin which use internally while creating Link.

Finally, I found the solution with simple code snipped, and I am not going to use any of such **Hateoas** API's. I am not sure whether this solution will be compatible with Spring or not, but I tried in **SpringBoot-2.x** version. It's working fine for me.

```
@PostMapping("/students")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    Student savedStudent = studentRepository.save(student);
    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
        .buildAndExpand(savedStudent.getId()).toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

As per the above example, URL will return like http://localhost:8080/students/1. This might vary as per your configuration.

If you need to add any extra path next to students and before id in the URL, you can directly hard code at before {id} declaration, for example /search/{id}. So that actual URL would be look like http://localhost:8080/students/search/1

If in case, you are not configured students as part of searching student by id, and you configured some other path to access student by id, you can use the below code to load only context, path for example http://localhost:8080 and add hardcode/load from properties to uri.

```
URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/search/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(newCase.getCaseId()).toUri();
```

As per the above code snippet, returning URL would be look like http://localhost:8080/search/1. You can explore different methods available under the [ServletUriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html). I hope this would be clear.

Answer (score 0):

To get correct resource link easily, you should use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41956064/11152683 .

To return **not only location**, but also **newly created resource**, you could take this approach:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.EntityLinks;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.ExposesResourceFor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import sk.qpp.qaron.user.repository.QaronUser;

import java.net.URI;

@RepositoryRestController
@ExposesResourceFor(BookInstance.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor // lombok thing, autoviring all final attributes through ctor
public class BookInstanceController {
    private final EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @RequestMapping(value="/bookInstances", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<Object> createBookInstance(@RequestBody BookInstance bookInstance, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler){
        // save to database
        final BookInstance createdBookInstance = bookInstanceRepository.save(bookInstance);

        final PersistentEntityResource newEntityResource = resourceAssembler.toModel(createdBookInstance);
        Link link = entityLinks.linkToItemResource(QaronUser.class, createdBookInstance.getId()).expand();
        return ResponseEntity
                .created(URI.create(link.getHref()))
                .body(newEntityResource);
    }
}
```

Note that this example is using `@RepositoryRestController` instead of `@RestController`. This is crucial for wiring `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` and not getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entities is marked non-null but is null`.